# Flex - Disabling the transparent background overlay on a popup

Tags: apache-flex

I have a button in my flex app that creates a popup overtop of everything. However, it seems like flex automatically puts this transparent overlay overtop of the stage when this happens. How do I disable this? I have tried contentBackgroundAlpha="0" and backgroundAlpha="0" with no luck.

anyone know what the proper syntax is for disabling this transparency? I have been searching through the docs for a 30 minutes now looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I find the answer immediately after posting this :)

modal-transparency: 0.0;
modal-transparency-color: white;
modal-transparency-blur: 0;

Comment: It seems that just setting modality to false should work.    

pop = mx.managers.PopUpManager.createPopUp(pnl, TitleWindow, false);